# Upload and download MySQL IBD files from Google SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

It is possible to upload and/or download the MySQL IBD files (InnoDB's per-table tablespaces) to/from Google SQL?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Google Cloud SQL only allows [import and export of SQL files](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/import-export) (e.g. as produced by mysqldump).